# Clarification on design patterns in PHP

Tags: php, design-patterns, singleton, factory, strategy-pattern

I know very little about design patterns out there. In fact i never worked with one yet, as i always went for raw coding. But i think its time to enrich my knowledge on design patterns out there. Specially i want to know more about Factory, Singleton & Strategy design patterns. I googled about them of course but I still not clear about their differences, how to implement them etc.

If anyone can suggest me some good document where i can read much more, that would be very much helpful.

Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns is a very helpful website, with a lot of explanations and code samples, including PHP ones. I added very short summaries in my own words below. Disclaimer: because they summaries are very short, the may not be very accurate, but give you an idea on how the patterns compare.

**Factory Method**: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method
In short: you have a separate class that is responsible for creating instances of a certain class. This is to make sure that a class is always constructed 'in the right way'.

**Singleton Pattern**: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton
In short: only one instance of a singleton class is possible, the class itself has a static class variable that stores the instance, and a static method that returns the stored instance, or create one if it is not yet created.

**Strategy Pattern**: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy
In short: if there are multiple ways to solve some problem, provide a set of classes that each contain one implementation to the problem and let the client decide which implementation to use.

Comment: Thats a very good link provided. Thank you for that. One question, is there any way to compare them side by side? Plz let me know.

Comment: Is your answer still good if all links would be broken? No, -> Include the essential parts of your link in your answer!

Comment: William, I added short summaries to let you compare the patterns in a glance, and @Rizier to prevent that this answer becomes useless if the links become broken.

Comment: @JeroenNoten thnx brother for this. Much appreciate.